# Spring Boot Api Rest SSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have a Spring Boot Api Rest, but I have problems with SSL certificate.
When I use the application without configuring the HTTPS, it works fine as shown below:

**application.properties:**

```
server.port=8443
#security.require-ssl=true
#server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
#server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
#server.ssl.key-store-password=MyPass
#server.ssl.key-alias=opusclick
```

**Postman request:**

[image]

On the other hand, when I enable the HTTPS protocol:

**application.properties:**

```
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=MyPass
server.ssl.key-alias=opusclick
```

**Postman request:**

[image]

The strangest thing is that when I have the HTTPS configured, if I place a breakpoint in the controller response, returns the same response as when the HTTP protocol is enabled.

My question is why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just guess you use a self-signed SSL certificate.
Postman disables self-signed SSL certificates by default

You have to disable the *SSL certificate verification* in the postman-settings.

Just go into *Settings > General* and disable it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I try to achieve is that when making this same request from the browser it works. Because when I deactivate this option in Postman I have an answer?

Comment: I think the browser doesn't block the self signed certs but postman does by default.

Comment: I only doubt remains. And is that my certificate is not self-signed, I bought it from namecheap. why is it blocked?

Comment: I just googled and maybe this can help: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9459/2223/i-get-certificate-is-not-trusted-because-it-is-selfsigned-error-message-when-i-visit-my-site/